# In the code below, Is it is possible to return the response outside the if statement?

Tags: laravel

In the code below, Is it is possible to return the response outside the if statement?

```
if($staff->attendence == 0)
{
$response = ['message' => 'The Staff is absent']
return response($response,422)
}
```

Comment: Do edit what you have tried so far.. So that it easy to understand and can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if($staff->attendence == 0)
{
    //If stuff absent return response should be like this.
    $response = ['message' => 'The Staff is absent'];
    return response()->json($response, 422);
}

//Other wise if staff is present 
return response()->json(['message' => 'The staff is present.'], 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this??

```
if($staff->attendence == 0) {
  $response = ['message' => 'The Staff is absent']
  $flag = true;
}

if($flag) {
    return response($response,422);
}
```

Comment: I need to return two responses (i.e.) The staff is present or not with his staff_id in a  $response array outside the if statement, so that i can give the attendence status and id of the staff.

Comment: @Sathish, not getting what you are asking. Can you show some demo

Comment: I need to simply know that if I can return the response outside the if statement.

Comment: Yes, you can, why not?